# IOS making an object on view controller disappear after some time?

Tags: ios

As the title says I want one of my objects to disappear after some time.I searched the net about this subject there I can't find anything no answers or a tutorial so I ask it from here.

Example:

User opens the app.

view controller comes to screen and it has a label on it.

That label disappears after 5 seconds.

How can I do it ?

Do I need to use animations ?

I really prefer doing it without any animation (if making animation is easy then ok)

Can you explain it step by step please I will try to make my label disappear first then I will make a view object to disappear.I know its strange to want a view to disappear I can use another view controller but I don't want it I want to code it to disappear after time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is set a timer. For example,

```
//In your viewDidLoad method of your view controller
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

//In a method called hideLabel
- (void) hideLabel
{
    self.myLabel.hidden = YES;  //This assumes that your label is a property of your view controller
}
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Oke I will implement this code into my m file now.I will share the results with you in couple of minutes.

Comment: If for some strange reason it doesn't work, let me know exactly what's happening and perhaps post some of your code.

Comment: it worked thank you.Can I do this for a view object and if I make that view disappear the other objects attached to that view disappear too ?

Comment: Yes. In the hideLabel method just hidden ANY views that you no longer wish to see.

Comment: But views caused me problem : S when I write this code for a view and connect them at the storyboard that view became fullscreen then disappears and black screen comes why ? I corrected answer.

Comment: This seems like an entirely different problem.  Labels (like we used above) ARE views.  Therefore, the above code should work for ANY view.  For example if we want a UIButton to disappear just write `self.myButton.hidden = YES`.  If we want a generic view to disappear then just do something similar.

Comment: If you are doing `self.view.hidden = TRUE` this is probably a bad idea.  Each View Controller has a property called view that represents the entire screen (for the most part). There really is no need to hide this one.

Comment: Oke then I use an image view that will work for me too and I think it will work same as label.

Comment: Can we assign this order to a button ? If I write this code into Ibo button action and put the void func in it will it work ?

Comment: Yes, a button is a UIView thus it will work.  Pretty much everything that can be displayed on a screen is a type of UIView.  This includes, buttons, labels, tableviews, table cells, image views and pretty much any other graphical thing that you can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Start a timer like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(hideWithAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And then when the timer hits start an animation, which is easy enough:

```
- (void)hideWithAnimation {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                     animations:^{
                                     // Fade the label
                                     [myLabel setAlpha:0]
                                 };
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

Here is the documentation for UIView look for Class methods:

[UIView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: oww so we can fade it great I will try this too then I will let you know thanks

Comment: You can simplify it by getting rid of the timer and setting the delay parameter to 5.0 when creating the animation.

Comment: Can we assign this order to a button ? If I write this code into Ibo button action and put the void fund in it will it work ?